# Electron window resize toggle on hovering over an html element

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm creating a small project with Electron where when I hover over a heading of the window, the height of the window expands and when i mouse out of that heading it should return back to its original size. I implemented the setSize() function and it only expands the window on hover, but when I mouseout it does not go back to its original size. My source code is as follows: (the html and Javascript file for the front end and the main process (main.js) for the electron process which controls the window. While the console.log for both events gets triggered, the setSize does not work for the mouseout event.

Would greatly appreciate your feedback on this, where am I going wrong?

**page.html**

```
<div class="home">
  <h4 id="hom" class="hometext white">pipe</h4>
</div>
```

**page.js**

```
const electron = require("electron");
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

const myhome = document.getElementById("hom")

myhome.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  //createBrowserWindow();
  ipc.send("mouseover", "myred");
});
myhome.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  //createBrowserWindow();
  ipc.send("mouseout", "myred");
});
```

electron main process:
**main.js**

```
function createWindow() {
    smallWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
      title: "small app",
      width: 500,
      height: 400,
      alwaysOnTop: true,
      opacity: 1.0,
      frame: false,
      closable: true,
      backgroundColor: themeMain,
      resizable: false,
      x: 50,
      y: 55,
    });
    smallWindow.loadFile(`./app/smallwin/smallwin.html`);
}

    ipcMain.on("mouseover", () => {
        console.log('mouseover')
        smallWindow.setSize(500, 700)
      });
      ipcMain.on("mouseout", () => {
          console.log('mouseout')
        smallWindow.setSize(500, 400)
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your resizable value to true in your main.js